# How to install TF r1.3? - Tensorflow-gpu package not found from pip3 packages on win10

Tags: windows, pip, python-3.6, tensorflow

I tried to install Tensorflow-gpu r1.3 on Windows 10 using Python 3.6.

When I try to install it through pip3 as said in TF webpage, I get this error message:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow-gpu (from versions: )
>   No matching distribution found for tensorflow-gpu

After some googling I found suggestions that pip should be upgraded, but it is already up-to-date as I get this:

> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:...

Also when I run **pip3 search tensorflow** I find lots of other TF related packages, but neither **tensorflow** nor **tensorflow-gpu**.

So how can I get the latest tensorflow-gpu installed and preferably through pip3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tensoflow-gpu](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tensorflow-gpu) is available for 64-bit Python. You need to install  64-bit Python 3.6 and then `pip3 install tensoflow-gpu`.

Comment: Wow! I feel a bit dumb now, as this was it actually. Everything else I did right, but never ever even thought of checking whether I had installed the correct python.. uhhh. After installing the 64-bit Python everything went as expected.